# input mis match exception

Tags: java, exception

```
try
  {
     File f=new File(fname);
     Scanner k=new Scanner(f);
     Scanner k3=new Scanner(System.in);
     int drNr;
     String occ;
     int  adl;
     int child;
     while(k.hasNext())
     {
        drNr=k.nextInt();
        occ=k.nextLine();
        adl=k.nextInt();
        child=k.nextInt();
        k.nextLine();
        Room r=new Room(drNr,occ,adl,child);
        roomList.add(r);
     }
     k.close();
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     System.out.println("file not found");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println(e);
   }
```

the text file that is read is

```
111
John Adams
1
0
.
222
Paul Brake
2
1
.
333
George Clarke
2
2
.
4
```

its showing an inputmismatch exception

Comment: Welcome to SO. One of the first rules of asking for help with an exception is to include the COMPLETE stacktrace in your post.  Please edit your question and paste in the stacktrace; also, identiy the line in your code that throws the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line `occ=k.nextLine();` will be reading the newline character after the previous integer, instead of reading the line of text that you want it to read.  You need to insert an extra call to `k.nextLine()` before this.  You'll need the same when you read the dot at the end of each `Room` too.